# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Copy ViewModel to Business Objects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2.0 and I want to transfer my ViewModel properties to business object. I can do this manually or use AutoMapper or use new method available in ASP.NET MVC 2.0. My question is that does anyone know the name of the new method which allows to copy the properties from one object to another?

Comment: You aren't referring to UpdateModel are you?

Comment: No! It was something like CopyModel or something!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! But it is part of ASP.NET MVC Futures library! Sorry for the confusion.

```
ModelCopier.CopyModel(employeeViewModel, employee);
```

And here is the link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/03/31/easy-way-to-update-models-in-your-asp-net-mvc-business-layer.aspx